# How to check if my azure website instance count is getting utilized or not?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

So I have created one azure app plan with one app service.Pricing tier is S2 but **instance count is 4**. This is all the time set,  no automation is there to scale out.(Burning money for 4 instances)

Now I want to check if my app is using only 1 instance count or more than one over the time period , so that I can decide how many instance count we really need all the time 24*7*356.

Any metrics, app insight or portal through which I can check it.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the appservice plan?

Comment: When the instance count is > 1 the traffic will be distributed over the instances, so you won't be able to check if just one instance is used. Instead you can monitor cpu / memory usage.

Comment: I think CPU and Memory uses monitoring is not fluctuate so much but may be other parameter based metric could help... like data in or something else ..i am currently looking into what kind of parameter can give clear picture....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the following environment variable and log which instance name handled the request.

`WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID`

more info:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#website-environment-variables

PS: IMHO you should setup 2 instances and configure auto scaling based on metrics, and set alerts to be notified whenever it scale up/down. It's the best way to be sure you're not burning money.